# Nginx allow traffic from any domain

Tags: ssl, nginx, lets-encrypt, certbot

I'm using `nginx` for the proxy server. My application has a feature where user can use their own domain instead of my domain. For that, they need to point their CNAME to my domain.

This is my Nginx configuration

```
server {
  server_name                   scan.mydomain.com anonymous.mydomain.com "";
  access_log                    /etc/nginx/log/local-wc.access.log;
  error_log                     /etc/nginx/log/local-wc.error.log;

  location / {
    root                      /var/www/html/qcg-scanning-frontend/dist/webapp/;
    index                     index.html;
    try_files                 $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    proxy_redirect            off;
    proxy_set_header          Host            $host;
    proxy_set_header          X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header          X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header          X-Forwarded-Protocol $scheme;
  }

  listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
  ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/anonymous.mydomain.com-0001/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/anonymous.mydomain.com-0001/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
  include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
  ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
}

server {
  if ($host = scan.mydomain.com) {
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
  } # managed by Certbot

  if ($host = anonymous.mydomain.com) {
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
  } # managed by Certbot

  server_name                   scan.mydomain.com anonymous.mydomain.com "";
  listen 80;
  return 404; # managed by Certbot
}
```

this configuration is working fine when browsed using my domain `scan.mydomain.com` and `anonymous.mydomain.com` but using any pointed domain like `new.example.com`, it gives 404 page (maybe due to `return 404` statement).

For SSL, I'm using lets-encrypt certbot.

How can I configure to

1. Allow traffic from all CNAME pointed domains to my server?
2. Provide SSL certificate to all the domains?

Comment: Did you find the solution? I need help!

Comment: come on we need solution for this question

Comment: @RohitLakhotia and I moved to the Caddy server which is far better than nginx. Check the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used CaddyServer which is far better than nginx and satisfies all requirements.

https://caddyserver.com/

Features of Caddy

- Support for third party domain CNAME pointing
- JSON based configuration
- API support for the configuration
- On-demand TLS
- Default serves SSL/TLS to all the domains in the production server
- No hassle to install and manage SSL certificates for the domains.